# Adding column from dataframe with different structure

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two dataframe structures:

```
            roc_100
            max                 min
industry    Banks     Health    Banks   Health
date
2015-03-15  3456      456       345     567
2015-03-16  6576      565       435     677
2015-03-17  5478      657       245     123
```

and:

```
            roc_100
            max       min
date
2015-03-15  546       7856
2015-03-16  677       456
2015-03-17  3546      346
```

As can be seen the difference between the two dataframes is that the bottom one doesn't have an 'industry'. But the rest of the dataframe structure is the same, ie: it is also has dates along the left, and is grouped by roc_100, under which is max and min.

What I need to do is add the columns from the bottom dataframe to the top dataframe, and give the added columns an industry name, eg: 'benchmark'. The resulting dataframe should be as follows:

```
            roc_100
            max                              min
industry    Banks     Health    Benchmark    Banks   Health    Benchmark
date
2015-03-15  3456      456       546          345     567       7856
2015-03-16  6576      565       677          435     677       456
2015-03-17  5478      657       3546         245     123       346
```

I have tried using append and join, but neither option has worked so far because the one dataframe has an 'industry' and the other doesn't.

**Edit:**

I have managed to merge them correctly using:

```
industry_df = industry_df.merge(benchmark_df, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

The only problem now is that the newly added columns still don't have an 'industry'.

This means that if I just want one industry, eg: Health, then I can do:

```
print(industry_df['roc_100', 'max', 'Health'])
```

That works, but if I want to print all the industries including the newly added columns I can't do that. If I try:

```
print(industry_df['roc_100', 'max'])
```

This only prints out the newly added columns because they are the only ones which don't have an 'industry'. Is there a way to give these newly merged columns a name ('industry')?

Comment: Check out the [``merge``](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) command - it's incredibly versatile, and let's you choose which columns to merge on the left and right, index or not; also what to do with merged columns.

Comment: Thanks @AmiTavory I have managed to merge them correctly but have run into a problem. Please see my edit of the original question. Thank you.

Comment: In general, once you have a DataFrame ``df`` in the shape you want, things are good. ``df.columns`` is just a regular Python list, and you can rename the columns any way you want. A list of tuples makes it multilevel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stack() and unstack() to bring two dataframes to identical index structures with industries as columns. Then assign new benchmark column. Last step - restore initial index/column structure by same stack() and unstack().